# Incorrect permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, exchange-server

I've created a runbook in Azure Automation that runs a few commands including the following:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $shared_mailbox -User $mailbox_user -AccessRights FullAccess -Confirm:$false
Write-Output  "Granting full access permission..."
Add-RecipientPermission -Identity $shared_mailbox -Trustee $mailbox_user -AccessRights SendAs -Confirm:$false
Write-Output  "Granting full send permission..."
```

However when running the Add-RecipientPermission Cmdlet it throws the following error.

> |Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.InsufficientPermissionsException|Source
> server:xxxx.prod.exchangelabs.com doesn't have write permission to
> target DC:xxxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM. Usually it indicates that target
> forest isn't an account partition of source forest. Additional
> information: Access is denied. Active directory response: 00000005:
> SecErr: DSID-03152E13, problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0

I've given it Exchange Admin permissions to the service account which is why add-mailbox permission works, but unsure why the second command does not work

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now I created the **Service Principal** using below commands:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString 'TestExchangeApp'
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString $app.DisplayName
$sp1 = New-ServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId -ServiceId $sp.ObjectId -DisplayName "Exchange Service Principal for $($app.DisplayName)"
```

[image]

Now, `Add-MailboxPermission` and `Add-RecipientPermission` commands worked successfully like below:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "user1@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -User $sp1.ServiceId -AccessRights FullAccess

Add-RecipientPermission -Identity "user1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -Trustee "user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"  -AccessRights SendAs
```

[image]
[image]

> **If you want to **assign permission to the Service Account**, check the below**:

You can **check what Exchange Command needs which permissions**:

```
 Get-ManagementRole -Cmdlet Add-RecipientPermission
 
 Get-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role "Mail Recipients" -Delegating $false | Format-Table -Auto Role,RoleAssigneeType,RoleAssigneeName
```

[image]

**Hence to resolve the error**, assign **`Recipient Management`**/**`Organization Management`** role to the user like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Permissions in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions-exo/permissions-exo)